# Assigning ViewController's view to a custom View class won't show the custom View properties

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

The following code allows me to access the testView property of `WalkthroughView`.

```
class WalkthroughViewController: UIViewController{

    var walkthroughView = WalkthroughView()

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = walkthroughView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        walkthroughView.testView.backgroundColor = .cyan
    }
}
```

The following code doesn't allow me to access the testView property of `WalkthroughView`.

```
class WalkthroughViewController: UIViewController{

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = WalkthroughView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //cant access the .testView
        self.view.testView.backgroundColor = .cyan //this doesn't compile
    }
}
```

How is this possible? The first example creates an object of `WalkThroughView` which is assigned to self.view. Calling this object later allows me to change it's properties. The second example assigns the `WalkthroughView()` to the ViewController's view, with this approach it's (as far as I know) not possible to access the `WalkthroughView` properties.

Why doesn't the second approach allow me to access the `WalkthroughView` `testView` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example you are defining an instance variable walkThroughView of type WalkThroughView. You then reference it through that new variable with a special type.

In your second example, you create a new WalkthroughView instance and store it into the view controller's view property, and then reference it thorough the existing view property. The compiler doesn't know that self.view contains a variable of type WalkThroughView. You would need to cast it for that to be legal.

```
if let walkthroughView = self.view as? WalkThroughView {
   walkthroughView.testview.backgroundColor = .cyan
}
```

Comment: Great and simple explanation. Thank you so much! However shouldn't the code be changed to if var walkthroughView?

Comment: `If let` or `if var`, yes. I fixed my answer.